# Parent eval (reader) function in Clojure source?

Tags: clojure, scheme, eval

In [Peter Norvig's](http://norvig.com/) epic tome [Paradigms of Artifical Intelligence Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html) in Chapter 7 - he describes a function `interp` which is effectively a simple `eval` function used when interpreting a bare-bones Scheme in a REPL.

```
(defun interp (x &optional env)
  "Interpret (evaluate) the expression x in the environment env."
  (cond
    ((symbolp x) (get-var x env))
    ((atom x) x)
    ((case (first x)
       (QUOTE  (second x))
       (BEGIN  (last1 (mapcar #'(lambda (y) (interp y env))
                              (rest x))))
       (SET!   (set-var! (second x) (interp (third x) env) env))
       (IF     (if (interp (second x) env)
                   (interp (third x) env)
                   (interp (fourth x) env)))
       (LAMBDA (let ((parms (second x))
                     (code (maybe-add 'begin (rest2 x))))
                 #'(lambda (&rest args)
                     (interp code (extend-env parms args env)))))
       (t      ;; a procedure application
               (apply (interp (first x) env)
                      (mapcar #'(lambda (v) (interp v env))
                              (rest x))))))))
```

Interestingly enough - the opening Chapter of [Christian Queinnec's](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/Queinnec.html) [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) has a very similar function, he calls it `eval`.

```
;;; This is a naive evaluator for Scheme written in naive Scheme.

(define (evaluate e env)
  (if (atom? e) 
      (cond ((symbol? e) (lookup e env))
            ((or (number? e) (string? e) (char? e)
                 (boolean? e) (vector? e) )
             e )
            (else (wrong "Cannot evaluate" e)) )
      (case (car e)
        ((quote)  (cadr e))
        ((if)     (if (evaluate (cadr e) env)
                      (evaluate (caddr e) env)
                      (evaluate (cadddr e) env) ))
        ((begin)  (eprogn (cdr e) env))
        ((set!)   (update! (cadr e) env (evaluate (caddr e) env)))
        ((lambda) (make-function (cadr e) (cddr e) env))
        (else     (invoke (evaluate (car e) env)
                          (evlis (cdr e) env) )) ) ) )
```

My question is - where is the Clojure source is the equivalent `eval`/`interp` function? I assume it is in the reader code somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean, what's Clojure's `eval` procedure? That'd be [clojure.core/eval](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/eval). This [link](http://clojure.org/evaluation) from the documentation shows how evaluation occurs:

- Interactively, in the REPL
- On a sequence of forms read from a stream, via load or load-file
- Programmatically, via `eval`

If you're interested in the *actual* source code, take a look at Clojure's [`core.clj`](http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) file. In particular, the code for `eval` looks like this:

```
(defn eval
  "Evaluates the form data structure (not text!) and returns the result."
  [form] (. clojure.lang.Compiler (eval form)))
```

In turn, the `eval` method from the `Compiler` class (referenced in the above snippet, and residing in the [Compiler.java](http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) file) looks like this:

```
public static Object eval(Object form) throws Exception{
    boolean createdLoader = false;
    if(true)//!LOADER.isBound())
        {
        Var.pushThreadBindings(RT.map(LOADER, RT.makeClassLoader()));
        createdLoader = true;
        }
    try
        {
        Integer line = (Integer) LINE.deref();
        if(RT.meta(form) != null && RT.meta(form).containsKey(RT.LINE_KEY))
            line = (Integer) RT.meta(form).valAt(RT.LINE_KEY);
        Var.pushThreadBindings(RT.map(LINE, line));
        try
            {
            form = macroexpand(form);
            if(form instanceof IPersistentCollection && Util.equals(RT.first(form), DO))
                {
                ISeq s = RT.next(form);
                for(; RT.next(s) != null; s = RT.next(s))
                    eval(RT.first(s));
                return eval(RT.first(s));
                }
            else if(form instanceof IPersistentCollection
                    && !(RT.first(form) instanceof Symbol
                         && ((Symbol) RT.first(form)).name.startsWith("def")))
                {
                FnExpr fexpr = (FnExpr) analyze(C.EXPRESSION, RT.list(FN, PersistentVector.EMPTY, form), "eval");
                IFn fn = (IFn) fexpr.eval();
                return fn.invoke();
                }
            else
                {
                Expr expr = analyze(C.EVAL, form);
                return expr.eval();
                }
            }
        finally
            {
            Var.popThreadBindings();
            }
        }
    catch(Throwable e)
        {
        if(!(e instanceof CompilerException))
            throw new CompilerException((String) SOURCE.deref(), (Integer) LINE.deref(), e);
        else
            throw (CompilerException) e;
        }
    finally
        {
        if(createdLoader)
            Var.popThreadBindings();
        }
}
```

I guess that's not quite what you expected it to be, but given the fact that Clojure runs on top of the JVM, it makes sense that the evaluation part occurs as a Java program and not as a Lisp program - as is the case in the code referenced in the question.

Comment: OP is now very disappointed -- he found out Clojure's dirty secret that eval is not Clojure :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indeed! . And so am I - I mean, a little disappointed :/

Comment: Great - thanks for this. Would I be correct in assuming that ClojureScript doesn't have an eval function? That was the impression I got from watching the Rich Hickey ClojureScript intro talk.

Comment: @hawkeye That's right, ClojureScript doesn't have `eval`. This [post](http://blog.fogus.me/2011/07/29/compiling-clojure-to-javascript-pt-2-why-no-eval/) explains the reasons in detail