# Good place to start studying the source code for Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to study the official Clojure implementation. Can anyone who is familiar with the code recommend where to start reading it from? Are there certain parts which will make understanding the rest of it easier, or which are key to understanding how Clojure works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some big ideas in there - that may not be apparent until you're familiar with implementing a LISP.

So even before you look at the Clojure code - you might want to look at the code for a basic LISP implementation (there are heaps online - [this is one of my favourites](http://nakkaya.com/2010/08/24/a-micro-manual-for-lisp-implemented-in-c/)).

Next I'd read a book like Christian Quinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521562473) (LISP) which is a [book about implementing LISP compilers](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) - to get the paradigms.

In terms of actually starting in the Clojure source - I'd start with `eval` - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10462352/15441).

Comment: Thanks -- I read the source for the simple Lisp implementation you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

the clojurescript compiler is also an excellent place to start.

as far as the original clojure compiler,
I would start at the bottom of core.clojure and read
upwards so you can see the tendency for each part to build
on the features defined above (also try top to bottom and
find what works for you)